# Rails / Devise / Omniauth combo says email is nil but it's not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I was setting up Devise & Omniauth as per railscasts like I usually do, only now I'm using Rails 5.0.1 and ruby 2.3.3

When I go to add a user, not even using Omniauth, just using a basic email + password + confirmation the page reloads with an error of "Email can't be blank". I can see the parameters include the email.

I used Pry to investigate - things get weird here.

```
[1] pry(#<RegistrationsController>)> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[removed this!]", "user"=><ActionController::Parameters {"email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"testtest", "password_confirmation"=>"testtest"} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Sign up", "controller"=>"registrations", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
[3] pry(#<RegistrationsController>)> @user
=> #<User id: nil, email: "test@test.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, image_url: nil, headline: nil, dob: nil, gender: nil, webpage_url: nil, twitter: nil, linkedin: nil, blog_url: nil, description: nil, country: nil, state: nil, city: nil, phone: nil, full_bio: nil, profile_claimed: nil>
[4] pry(#<RegistrationsController>)> @user.class
=> User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, first_name: string, last_name: string, image_url: string, headline: string, dob: date, gender: string, webpage_url: string, twitter: string, linkedin: string, blog_url: string, description: text, country: string, state: string, city: string, phone: string, full_bio: text, type: string, profile_claimed: boolean)
[5] pry(#<RegistrationsController>)> @user.email
=> nil
[7] pry(#<RegistrationsController>)> @user.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f9de2c82da0
 @base=
  #<User id: nil, email: "test@test.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, image_url: nil, headline: nil, dob: nil, gender: nil, webpage_url: nil, twitter: nil, linkedin: nil, blog_url: nil, description: nil, country: nil, state: nil, city: nil, phone: nil, full_bio: nil, profile_claimed: nil>,
 @details={:email=>[{:error=>:blank}, {:error=>:blank}]},
 @messages={:email=>["can't be blank"], :password=>[], :password_confirmation=>[]}>
[8] pry(#<RegistrationsController>)> @user.email.class
=> NilClass
```

You can see that if I access @user it returns the hash containing the email. However if I try @user.email I get nil. And when I ask for @user.errors the message says email can't be blank.

I've been hunting a while on this one. Thanks in advance for any help!

--

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email])
  end
end
```

---

Puma server.

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2017-01-07 20:42:57 -0500
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tfBeZtXEFdZV9Rx3dJgCQJ+9hHuvgFcbc3dD9D7Q6yKki4GmlVw17/qlDm2squ3hKngX3Juu12iaM1Dki9qXig==", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.6ms)
```

--
rails console

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 12578
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.1)
2.3.3 :001 > u = User.new
 => #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, image_url: nil, headline: nil, dob: nil, gender: nil, webpage_url: nil, twitter: nil, linkedin: nil, blog_url: nil, description: nil, country: nil, state: nil, city: nil, phone: nil, full_bio: nil, profile_claimed: nil> 
2.3.3 :002 > u.email = "test@test.com"
 => "test@test.com" 
2.3.3 :003 > u.password = "password"
 => "password" 
2.3.3 :004 > u.password_confirmation = "password"
 => "password" 
2.3.3 :005 > u.save
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => false 
2.3.3 :006 > u.errors
 => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f87163eeac8 @base=#<User id: nil, email: "test@test.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, image_url: nil, headline: nil, dob: nil, gender: nil, webpage_url: nil, twitter: nil, linkedin: nil, blog_url: nil, description: nil, country: nil, state: nil, city: nil, phone: nil, full_bio: nil, profile_claimed: nil>, @messages={:email=>["can't be blank"]}, @details={:email=>[{:error=>:blank}, {:error=>:blank}]}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `permitted: false` says that your parameters are not permitted and can't be saved. Did you set up strong parameters for Users controller?

Comment: I had done in the application controller. as per: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise. "In case you want to permit additional parameters (the _lazy way™_), you can do so using a simple before filter in your ApplicationController. Edited original to show.

Comment: There's  `'` in `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base'` in the snippet.

Is it in your project code too?

Comment: Anyway I'd suggest you to check twice whether your parameter are permitted or not. For example if your development server is WebRick you'll see exactly unpermitted parameters message in it's log while trying to make request with unpermitted parameters

Comment: Thanks for the help VAD. Ok, I'm not exactly sure how to do that. I've got the Puma gem installed. in the terminal output when running the server and I hit that. Now editing post with that output.

Comment: As your server and conslose output say, rails tries to save your User, but can't do that and performs rollback. Apparently it's because of either validattions or strong_parameters.

To begin with you could try to just edit your `configure_permitted_parameters` like this:

`def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])`

If that wouldn't help, add to your question Users Registrations Controller and/or Users Controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132615/discussion-between-vad-and-sthoward).

Comment: Thanks @vad. I'm not sure what happened but it was wasting enough time to go rebuild that functionality instead.